# How to change max or min value of input type date from JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input type dates like:

```
<input type="date" name="first_date">
```

and other like:

```
<input type="date" name="second_date" min="first_date">
```

now what I want to do is that when `first_date` is selected than the minimum range of the `second_date` is auto filled by javascript.

Any idea how to do this.

Comment: Ajax ([tag:ajax] (Stack Overflow) [Ajax (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))) (strongly) *implies* that you're expecting to get a response from a server to do something; from your question it sounds as if you want to just JavaScript (entirely client-side). Could you clarify?

Comment: Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) *is* JavaScript; but I guess you mean client-side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic JavaScript using an onchange event to set the attribute.

```
document.getElementById("firstDateId").onchange = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("secondDateId");
    input.setAttribute("min", this.value);
}
```

Code could be better using addEventListener.

Comment: Well are you using a browser that support min on an html date input? Not all browsers support min on that field yet. http://jsfiddle.net/R76AZ/1/

Comment: Im using opera. And it does support min attribute. I tried your code like this. `<input type="date" id="first_date" name="first_date" onchange='var input = document.getElementById("second_date");input.setAttribute("min", this.value);'>
` and it works but when i write it between `<script>` tag it does not work.

Comment: Well you are probably adding it before the element is rendered. Is there errors in the console? The code needs to be added on dom ready, window onload, or after the element.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with epascarello’s answer, only you can replace `setAttribut("min/max")` with simply `.min` or `.max`.

```
document.getElementById("firstDateId").onchange = function ()
{
  var input = document.getElementById("secondDateId");
  input.min = this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use JavaScript's `.setAttribute('min',date)` on the element.  Check with the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) for details.  There's also jQuery's `.attr('min',date)` if you want to use a library.