# <input id="expiry" type="month" min="2016-05"> How to fill up the "min" attribute dynamically with current date?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out a way to fill "min" with the current date. So the calender will only start from the current month. Using html and javascript.

Comment: what about showing us an example of what you have so far?

Comment: Please, elaborate your question. What have you done so far ? Please, show some code examples

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611774/how-to-change-max-or-min-value-of-input-type-date-from-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your input with an id and then change its attribute, as so:

`<input id="monthPicker" type="month"/>`

And then in js:

```
var d = new Date(); //Current date
document.getElementById.setAttribute("min", d.getMonth()); //Set min to current month
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? It uses your computer's current date.

Comment: Care to explain why downvoted? Is it because I answered a question that wasnt clear enough?

Comment: I used to have a downvote for some reason. :D Now my life is better.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you mean?

```
    <input id='expiry' type='month' min=''>
<script>

var date = new Date();

var minTxt=date.getFullYear()+"-"+date.getMonth();
document.getElementById('expiry').min=minTxt;

</script>
```